# Aw Snap on my Google App Engine webpage on all browsers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

Hello Developers I am making an application using Google App Engine , Python Flask but I am getting Aw Snap error on trending events page , I am running this view on the page

```
@app.route('/events/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def trending_events():
    events= model.Event.query()
    return render_template('trending_events.html', events=events)
```

Here is the link to the Hosted Application: http://gcdc2013-eventus.appspot.com/events/

I am able to run this page perfectly on localhost but I am getting problem only on app engine server on the other hand I am able to view events in user profiles at Google App Engine.

Do I need to define Indexes ( but as there is no filter in the query that would be okay ) but for more better means please have a look at my Event NDB Model

```
class Event(Base,modelx.EventX):
    '''
    Refering Google + and Facebook Event model , also 
    customizing to generate team based events performance reports and visualizations 
    '''
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True,required=True)
    creator = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User", required=True)
    creator_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    event_type = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    teamSize = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    manager = ndb.StringProperty()
    event_url = ndb.StringProperty()
    description=ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    phone = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0000000000)
    venue = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    sdate = ndb.DateProperty()
    edate = ndb.DateProperty()
    googleplus_page = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    facebook_page = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    twitter_id = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    access = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Comment: Run the app in debug mode so that you can see a stack trace of the error.

Comment: Debug Mode is set True and I am getting `WARNING in toolbar [/home/chitrank/Documents/Google_App_Engine/GoogleCloudPlatform/uscore-stiteration/uscore/src/lib/flask_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py:48]:
Disabled SQLAlchemyDebugPanel due to ImportError: cannot import name json` on my local machine may be it is due to json, I am using
`import json` should i user `from flask import json`

Comment: Can you disable the debug toolbar and run the app with the regular debug mode enabled? If that works fine then the problem is in the debug toolbar. If you get a stack trace then that will likely be the problem in your own code instead of a warning from the toolbar.

Comment: you have got it right Miguel Actually I was using Google App Engine Mini Profiler and Flask-DebugToolbar that had some unfulfilled dependencies of json data , I removed them from my application and now my application is working super fine thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logs on the GAE admin page.

Most likely your event handler has an error that shows up when running on production, but not on your local server.  A common cause for this is not handling some case where the data on the real datastore is different from data on your dev server (ie, a query that returns nothing).

Comment: thank you dragonx Google App Engine Mini Profiler for Flask and Flask-DebugToolbar were the issue those were not running on production and when I removed them the production site works thank you.